# Dell XPS 13 shuts down/reboots rather than suspends/resumes

Tags: suspend, dell, power-management, laptop

It used to work fine: I would close the lid and Ubuntu would nicely suspend and resume when I opened the lid.

Now I find that it does not. What happens first, I don't know, but on reopening the lid, the computer boots up as if from a cold start. The same thing happens when I run `sudo pm-suspend`, so it has nothing to do with the lid settings--it's just that the suspend command seems to simply reboot.

I have been messing with `libinput` around the time when it happened, installing and uninstalling it and alternating with the synaptics driver, but I'm unsure if this is related.

- OS ver: Linux kernel 4.10.0-28-generic #32~16.04.2-Ubuntu
- System: Dell XPS 13 9350 (late 2015), i7 Skylake processor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very strange and it may have worked only for me, but whenever this happens to me, I shut down the computer entirely (power off). Upon restarting, the computer suspends/resumes normally.

I read this somewhere else but cannot find the source again.

Answer (score 2):

Similar model (Dell XPS 15 9550), same problem. Updating the BIOS to version `1.2.29` fixed this.

For future reference:

You can easily install BIOS updates on Debian using the package `fwupdmgr`.

Answer (score 0):

Well just as I finally decided to Ask Ubuntu, it stopped happening of course. Unsure what I did, but I followed some guidance from other, similar questions. One of which was to do a full poweroff (shut down, and restart with power button), rather than reboots. The other was to run another `sudo apt dist-upgrade` which seemed to also update some kernel headers.

Comment: Please delete the question, as the problem fixed itself and you are not sure what exactly solved the problem.

Comment: I worry that this might get me blocked. It may also be a guideline for others.

Comment: I already flagged it as "a problem that went away and can't be reproduced". What probably happened was an update that solved it. Always fully update after installing.

Comment: In fact, I had. I just went and did it again. It most certainly did not work for a week. I didn't think kernel headers would be updated weekly, anyway I'm not sure where to find information about the recent kernel updates

Comment: the issue just started happening again (yesterday) and I don't seem to have updated any headers recently.

Comment: I found the solution. Completely turning off the computer and restarting it has suspend/resume working perfectly.